# Anyone looking for some [arrow-keys]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [arrow-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-keys) tag seems fairly ambiguous. Arrow keys don't strike me as something that can explicitly be a problem (and if they are, it's probably better for [Super User](http://superuser.com)). Glancing through the first couple of questions seems to suggest that it doesn't really add anything meaningful to the questions that use it.

Its tag wiki appears to confirm this:

> The up, down, left, and right keys on a keyboard, also known as "cursor keys".

It doesn't seem like a very good tag. Can we get rid of it?

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for the ["any key"](http://www.troll.me/images/home-simpson-panic/press-any-key-to-continue-cant-find-the-any-key.jpg)

Comment: Looking at the [tagged posts sorted by score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-keys?sort=votes&pageSize=50), I have to respectfully disagree regarding burnination -- there are plenty of questions specifically regarding the arrow keys.  Some retagging cleanup is still in order.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Most of those are old, barely on-topic (if at all) questions that could be migrated to Super User or closed. While there *are* plenty specifically regarding arrow keys, this specific tag doesn't actually add much meaning to the question. If a tag is necessary for that particular topic, perhaps [tag:keyboard] would be better.

Comment: @AstroCB You're going to punt those questions about disabling/simulating the arrow keys using JavaScript to Super User?  Perhaps we're not looking at the same page -- most of those seem like programming questions to me.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I'm talking more about ones like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471558/macos-keyboard-a-way-to-speed-up-the-left-and-right-arrow-keys-for-editing-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225070/is-it-possible-to-use-arrow-keys-in-ocaml-interpreter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/python-shell-arrow-keys-do-not-work-on-remote-machine, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460514/vim-custom-arrow-key-mappings-not-working-with-window-switching (most of which seem to be the top questions you're talking about).

Comment: Also [tag:user-interface] may be more appropriate for some of the valid questions in the tag, instead.

Comment: @AstroCB First and last should go.  Middle two are about programming languages REPLs, which would seem to be on topic here?  I'm all for cleaning up what doesn't belong, I just think there will be enough on-topic posts like https://stackoverflow.com/q/10520472 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719023 to justify keeping the tag around afterward.  Let's clean up first and reevaluate.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom what do you think about [tag:capslock], [tag:shift], [tag:num-lock], [tag:ctrl], [tag:alt], etc.? Do you believe that we need a tag for each and everyone key of the standard 101-keys keyboard (this naturally excludes the composite key)?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I believe both of those questions would be equally well-served by [tag:keyboard], but also agree that a cleanup beforehand will give more clarity.

Comment: Oh, btw, [tag:alt] is used indistinctly for both the alt html element and the alt key...

Comment: @Braiam Which also makes one question the value of tags for individual HTML *attributes*... but I digress.

Comment: What about the [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) tag?

Answer (score 25):

I agree with AstroCB's point about [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) being appropriate, and suggest retagging [arrow-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-keys) questions to [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) (if the question is lower level or specific to keyboard input) and/or [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) (if it's more of a general UI topic) or untagging entirely (if the tag was used inappropriately to begin with), burninating [arrow-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-keys), followed by a general case-by-case post cleanup.

I do not see a need for tags that are specific subsets of keyboard keys, this adds no real value over [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) itself.