# No more time for the flaming [arrow]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

There are 465 questions tagged with [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow). [Its tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arrow/info) is a plea for burnination, and suggests we use [arrow-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-keys) and [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows), but those should *also* be burninated:

- [burninate-request for arrow-keys](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287639/anyone-looking-for-some-arrow-keys)
- [burninate-request about arrows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266975/is-there-a-need-for-the-haskell-arrows-tag).

I suggest we remove [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) and replace its various usages like so:

- arrow keys: **[keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) (see [burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287639/anyone-looking-for-some-arrow-keys))**
- arrows, the model of computational effects: **[haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) (see [burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266975/is-there-a-need-for-the-haskell-arrows-tag))**
- Arrow, a Python time library: **[arrow-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-python)**
- drawing an arrow or arrows in user interfaces: **remove**
- the `->` operator in C: **remove**
- arrow functions in JavaScript: **[arrow-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-functions) (see [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340731))**

Comment: arrow functions in JavaScript: remove. Yes, but apply ecmascript-6

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +68/-4. A1 (saying yes):  +11/-3. A2 (saying nothing): +10/0. A3 (saying No): 0/-10. A4 (saying yes): +4/-2.

Comment: Moderator Notes: 1. There are many valuable discussion answers here, so please go through each of them. 2. The burnination is for [tag:arrow] only and not about [tag:arrows] or [tag:arrow-keys], please keep your arguments to/for the [tag:arrow] only. 3. As we're starting this on a Friday, it will remain [featured] through the weekend and would be decided on Monday.

Comment: Shoot the arrow tag.

Comment: There's a [tag:pointers] that the C -> questions can be tagged with. I'm well aware that most of these are going to be terrible questions that just get deleted anyway. On further checking the only good questions already have the [tag:pointers] already anyway.

Comment: @paqogomez [tag:arrow] must take a [meta-tag:bow]

Comment: Should the arrow tag shoot through?   *ouch* Splinter. :-p

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +115/-5. A1 (saying yes):  +21/-9. A2 (saying nothing): +19/0. A3 (saying No): +1/-21. A4 (saying yes): +9/-5. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- For questions concerning arrow keys use [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard). [Do not use the [arrow-keys] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287639/anyone-looking-for-some-arrow-keys).
- For arrows in the haskell language, use  [haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) (see [Is there a need for the [haskell-arrows] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266975/is-there-a-need-for-the-haskell-arrows-tag))
- For questions related to [Arrow, a Python time library](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), use [arrow-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-python)
- Most of the questions concerning the  `->` operator in C is related to pointers, for which [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers) can be used.
- For questions related to the fat arrow functions in JavaScript use [arrow-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-functions). If the problem is about immediately invoked function expressions,  and not unique to fat arrow functions, it should use [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda).
- Use the [arrowdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrowdb) for questions related to Arrow DB, the cloud management REST APIs.
- For [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) questions about drawing arrows, use [css-shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes)
- for any questions about drawing an arrow or arrows in user interfaces, you can remove the tag.

## Progress:

The [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=arrow),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barrow%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barrow%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barrow%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barrow%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

Some additional links:

- [Questions tagged [arrow] but have "keys" in them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barrow%5D+keys+is%3Aq&mixed=0), most of these should be retagged with [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard).

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178025/burnination-progress-for-the-arrow-tag)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: What's the "roombad" in the burnination progress?

Comment: deleted by roomba, https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Answer (score 21):

> - arrows, the model of computational effects: [haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) (see [burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266975/is-there-a-need-for-the-haskell-arrows-tag))

As a preliminary measure, I have retagged the 8 questions with both [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) to use [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows). As things stand now, all [129 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows+haskell) tagged with both [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) are about "the model of computational effects". That being so, should there be a consensus in favour of burninating [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows), those questions can be retagged to something more specific without further ado, and it will only be necessary to consider [the remaining 54 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows+-haskell).

As for the fate of [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows), I am pretty much indifferent, as long as this sense of "arrows" ends up with a specific tag for itself. While its current tag wiki...

> Arrows are a means of modeling computational effects that are more general and less powerful than Monads. [...]

... matches the "model of computational effects" meaning, I agree that "arrows" on its own sounds prone to mistagging. [haskell-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-arrows) is a decent, though not perfect, alternative -- it is a bit too specific, as the concept is not necessarily bound to Haskell (I could find two non-Haskell [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows) questions, [one with F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows+f%23) and [another with Agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows+agda) -- make of that what you will). [In an answer to the burnination request mentioned above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267069/2751851), 
Ganesh Sittampalam speculates about a third tag, which might work if we figured out a convincing choice. I find the [arrows-abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows-abstraction) suggestion there rather clunky; [Andrey Tyukin's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340724/should-we-burninate-the-arrow-tag/340733?noredirect=1#comment620344_340733) of using [hughes-arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hughes-arrows) sounds much nicer to me.

Comment: Whose idea was to use [arrows] instead of [haskell-arrows]? It's not a "cosmetic" difference, tags are cornerstone of SO because most of them can be identified with a glance what you expect the question to be about!

Comment: +1 I agree with the reasoning that `[haskell-arrows]` is workable but not ideal. Is `[arrow-typeclass]` slightly better?

Comment: @Braiam Just to make sure we are on the same page: what I called "cosmetic" was the concern about [tag:haskell-arrows] being too specific, and definitely not the one about [tag:arrows] being too general.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I can get behind that. I somehow understood that you were saying that [haskell] + [arrows] is ok.

Comment: @GordonGustafson It is slightly better, to the extent that it mentions, rather than a specific language, a language feature which is present in multiple languages (even if that is still a bit restrictive), and perhaps also because it begins, rather than ends, with "arrow". On the other hand, `[haskell-arrows]` might plausibly be read as "Arrows similar to those in Haskell"; such an interpretation comes a little less easily with `[arrow-typeclass]`.

Comment: I don't know why this post from 2017 is all of a sudden "hot", but how about a `[hughes-arrows]`-tag? I mean, at least in functional programming, "arrows" are associated with one very specific name of one very specific person who introduced the concept. The `[haskell-arrows]` is too narrow, because arrows can be used in other languages. `[arrow-typeclass]` conflates the arrows themselves with a specific type of polymorphism prevalent in haskell - this kind of polymorphism is also not strictly necessary for arrows. And "Haskell" is also just a name, after all.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That is a good idea; I have incorporated it to the answer. (The question is featured because [arrow] is, barring a solid objection, about to be burninated. [arrows] won't be affected for now, but I guess the burnination will have ripple effects over it.)

Answer (score 10):

> - arrow functions in JavaScript: **remove**

Come on, let's recognize these for what they are: lambdas. Let's retag these to [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda).

Comment: I seldom would do this mecanically, since the question could have nothing to do with lambdas, ie. I have some code with a problem and it has *lambdas* but that's not relevant.

Comment: @Braiam true, but you have to keep that in mind whenever you're tagging stuff.

Comment: `->` in C is member selection. C doesn't have lambdas.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah, okay. I'll go fix that.

Comment: Is the average person who comes across the JS "fat arrow" operator and comes here for a clue going to know to search for "lambda"?

Comment: @JohnHascall Those should be retagged to [`[arrow-functions]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-functions)

Comment: I agree `[arrow-functions]` is better than `[lambda]` there.

Comment: Aren't old-style Javascript function expressions (`function() {...}`) also [lambda] expressions? If a question arises from the different behavior of arrow functions vs function expressions, the tags won't reflect that.

Comment: Thank you Javascript for making everything harder.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Tags don't have to point you in the exact direction (like an arrow), they're for categorization. [lambda] is close enough.

Comment: @mbomb007 Except that in Javascript [tag:arrow-functions] is a distinct subset of [tag:lambda], because arrow functions in Javascript have unique semantics (e.g. `this` handling); there may be some questions that need to be categorized specifically under [tag:arrow-functions].

Comment: @ZevSpitz [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's too specific for a unique tag, imho. Every language implements lambdas a little differently, and we don't need a special tag for each lang's implementation.

Comment: I think that both [tag:lambda] and [tag:arrow-functions] can be appropriate depending on the question. If the question is about immediately invoked function expressions, but the problem is not unique to fat arrow functions, it should use [tag:lambda]. If the problem is unique to fat arrow functions, then both [tag:lambda] and [tag:arrow-functions] should be used.

Comment: Tagging all of them as [tag:lambda] *instead of* [tag:arrow-functions] is a terrible idea. It appears to be taking a limited view of what the `=>` operator can be used for, without regard to what the standard uses for nomenclature. The [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) explicitly calls them "arrow functions". Replacing the [tag:arrow-functions] tag with the [tag:lambda] tag just causes confusion. While the `=>` is commonly used to create a lambda, as `function` can also be used, it isn't exclusively used as such.

Answer (score 3):

> the -> operator in C: remove

**C**
The closest thing to a formal name for this operator is "the struct/union member operator". Informally this operator is called "member of" or "member of pointer to struct/union". It is sometimes referred to as "the arrow operator" but only informally.

**C++**
The operator is sometimes referred to as the *arrow operator*, both formally and informally, see for example C++11 5.2.5.

I propose that a new tag is created for this operator, to cover its use in both languages:

[arrow-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow-operator)

Comment: -1 In my opinion we almost never need a tag for specific operators. It seems rare that a question is truly *about* the usage of the arrow operator, and I don't think there are any experts (or aspiring experts) in it.

Comment: @GordonGustafson That may be because the arrow operator is straight-forward and trivial, without any hidden pitfalls. But almost all operators in C and C++ are rather complex, surrounded by oddities and special cases. Sequence points, special order of evaluation, implicit promotion rules, cases of undefined behavior. It takes a veteran to know all of that - an expert if you will. Certain operators are so odd that they definitely merit a tag of their own... and they already have it. Bitwise operators, conditional operator, comma operator, logical operators etc etc.

Comment: @GordonGustafson Come to think of it, the arrow and dot operators aren't that straight-forward... they involve the special case of common initial sequence for unions. A rather advanced topic, related to compatible type, effective type and type punning through unions. Nothing is ever simple in these languages...

Comment: Definitely good points. Do you think tagging those questions [tag:unions] is sufficient, or that we should *in addition* tag them with something like `member-of`?

Comment: `.` and `->` are also called "the member access operators"...

Comment: There's a [tag:pointers] that the questions can be homed to.

Answer (score -19):

I am in favor of disambiguation, but I usually like to keep the option of using a generic for those specific cases where they're relevant. Still, disambiguation is helpful, but how are tags populated? Let's say I want to use "arrow (symbol)" but all I can find are other versions of what arrow could mean. I may have to choose another term, which may be less specific (like "icon").

Comment: Just ask on Meta to have the tag created if you need a new meaning for [arrow].

Comment: Do you know any expert in "arrow (symbol)"?

Comment: @Didier the [hand-waving about a lack of experts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751) argument has been proven to be irrelevant time and time again. Can we drop that useless metric please?